# Cambiar el tamaño de un container en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy practicando con `bootstrap` y resulta que deseo modificar el `height` de un `container-fluid`, aplico las reglas en `css`, pero no puedo cambiar el tamaño, esto es lo que llevo:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Backgrounds */

#background-head {
  background: #000000;
}
/*Cambio de tamaño a los container*/

.container-fluid {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example1</title>
  <meta chartset="Utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheetStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="background-head">
    <div class="row">
      <header>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </header>
      <!-- header -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <section>
    <article></article>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JQUERY-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

No se porque no se aplica la regla de altura al container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que estás utilizando `max-height` en lugar de `height`.

Con `max-height:200px` lo que haces es decirle al navegador que el contenedor debe tener una altura máxima de 200px, pero no le das instrucciones sobre la altura que quieres, que puede ser cualquier cosa mientras que sea menos de 200 pixels. Si usas `height:200px` entonces le estás diciendo al navegador que el contenedor debe tener una altura exacta de 200 pixels.

Aquí tienes el código con el cambio, ahora el contenedor sí tiene una altura de 200:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Backgrounds */

#background-head {
  background: #000000;
}
/*Cambio de tamaño a los container*/

.container-fluid {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example1</title>
  <meta chartset="Utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheetStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="background-head">
    <div class="row">
      <header>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </header>
      <!-- header -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <section>
    <article></article>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JQUERY-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias era lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Me alegro de que haya servido :)

Comment: @juliansalas Si te sirvio la respuesta de Alvaro, aceptala como respuesta para que cuando más usuarios busquen una pregunta como la tuya, la puedan localizar más rápido :)

Answer (score 0):

Aplica el !important:

```
.container-fluid{
 max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: No me funciono, ya lo había intentado pero no resulta, lo hice con un padding-bottom, pero quiero hacerlo modificando el tamaño directamente.

Comment: y si lo mandas a un estilo en linea? style="height:200px; background-color:red;"

Comment: hahaha, echale tierrita al comentario, acabo de ver la respuesta! Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No tiene mucho sentido modificar el tamaño de un `container-fluid`, este está hecho para ocupar todo el bloque, si deseas modificar el ancho debes usar la clase `container` con un `width`....

En cuanto al alto deberías indicarle un tamaño solo con `height`.. Lo ideal es no tocar las clases de `Bootstrap` porque suelen reutilizarse, podrías agregar una `div` con clase o `id` ej. contenido o general y a esa darle las dimensiones que desees..

Por otro lado puede que algunas veces no te deje modificar clases de `Bootstrap`, generalmente lo solucionas agregando `!important` al valor que cambies... Pero nuevamente, lo ideal es no modificar las clases de `Bootstrap` y si precisas algo específico hacerlo dentro de una `div` y darle los estilos que desees...